# Trouble combining templates and class function overloading

Tags: c++, function, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

The code below works fine, printing out 50 as expected. What I am not understanding, however, is why the same program can't be written with a couple slight alterations to this code. The two lines of proposed code are marked Bad code 1 and 2. When these are substituted for the current working code to the left of them (i.e. in `addStuff` and `main`), I get the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'MyClass')|
```

The way I expected it to work was: when `addStuff(x,y)` gets called in the (bad) `cout` line of `main()`, it first evaluates `x+y`, the behavior of which is defined by the `operator+` MyClass overloaded member function. This should just return a MyClass object, which then has no trouble calling getVar.

What am I missing here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(){}
    MyClass(int a) : priV(a){}
    MyClass operator+(MyClass otherMC)
    {
        MyClass newMC;
        newMC.priV = this->priV + otherMC.priV;
        return newMC;
    }
    int getVar(){return priV;}
    void setVar(int v){priV=v;}
private:
    int priV;
};

template <class gen>
gen addStuff(gen x, gen y)
{
    return x+y;          //Bad code 1: return (x+y).getVar();
}

int main()
{
    MyClass x(20), y(30);
    cout << addStuff(x,y).getVar() << endl;    //Bad code 2: cout << addStuff(x,y) << endl;
}
```

Comment: bad code 1: returning wrong type. bad code 2: implement the ostream << for whatever type you want to handle there, or use getVar() like you did to explicitly convert to a type that ostream already handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation of what should happen in line 1, `return (x+y).getVar();` is correct. The overloaded `operator+` will get called on the arguments x and y, and `getVar()` will be called on the result of `operator+`. When x and y are of type MyClass, the operator+ call returns an object of type MyClass, so the call to `getVar()` works.

However, `getVar()` returns an int. Your function `addStuff` is specified to return `gen`, which is the same template parameter that matches the arguments x and y. This means that when x and y are MyClass, the `addStuff` function must return MyClass.

Thus, when you put `addStuff(x,y)` in your `cout` statement, the return type of `addStuff` is inferred to be MyClass. This is what makes your compiler produce the error that "there is no operator<< for type MyClass."

If you want `addStuff` to return the result of `getVar()`, you should declare it to return `int`, not `gen`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify `addStuff` so that it returns an `int`, not the template parameter `gen` (which will be `MyClass`):

```
template <class gen>
int addStuff (gen x, gen y)
{
    return (x + y).getVar ();
}
```

If you don't change `gen` into `int`, then the function will work fine because the constructor `MyClass(int a)` will be called explicitly and then the result will be an object of type `MyClass`.

And obviously the compiler will say that you cannot '`cout`' an object of type `MyClass`.

So i suggest you to mark the constructor with `explicit`:
Also your code didn't compile because there is no default constructor, so add one, or simply mark the parameter with a default value:

```
explicit MyClass (int a = 0) : priV (a) {}
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't want to change the return type of the function if you change the type of the member, you can use decltype, to make the code more generic:

```
template <class gen>
decltype (auto) addStuff (gen x, gen y)   //Or decltype (declval<gen> ().getVar ())
{
    return (x + y).getVar ();
}
```

Comment: Can't `auto` be used here?

Comment: Maybe... I've only used `auto` return types for simpler functions so far, hence the uncertainty.

Comment: Well yes..but with decltype you have an idea of what type the function will return.

Comment: Ok I've tried both: decltype(auto) (or the more verbose version I posted) is better because if the member has type int& (for example) then the function will return int, if you use "auto" as return type.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in `addStuff` function, it returns MyClass object, constructed from int variable. You need to modify this function to work with "bad code"

```
template <class gen>
int addStuff(gen x, gen y)
{
    return (x+y).getVar();
}
```

Or write an ostream operator for MyClass. For this you need to modify `getVar` method, include a friend declaration and implement it

```
int getVar() const { return priV; }
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const MyClass& m);
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const MyClass& m) {
    out << m.getVar();
    return out;
}
```

This way you don't need to modify `addStuff` function.

Side note, your code didn't compile for me because there was no default constructor in MyClass, had to modify constructor like this

```
MyClass(int a = 0) : priV(a) {}
```